# Indexing Json files in C#

Tags: c#, json, indexing

I am working on an c# application which needs to create a lot of json files.  Within this application there is the occasional need to be able to search the json files for a particular value.  Looping through all the files is not an option based on how many files there are.  Using a DB like MongoDB is also not an option.   The application is already creating all the json files, I am looking for a way to index the files, so that searching is fast and easy. I imagine I need a way to update the indexes when a json file is created or modified.  Please suggest any tools for indexing a lot of json files in c#.

Comment: This is non-trivial.  Have a look at the [RavenDB](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) code base.  This is exactly what they do.